# How to trigger SVG SMIL animation on CSS3 animation event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to trigger an SVG SMIL animation on CSS3 animation event. I've been researching this for a day or so and I can't get it to work. I'm not sure that this is even possible.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zVzq/3/)

```
// run script after ALL page content has loaded
$(window).load(function () {
    var a = document.getElementById('arm');
    //get the inner DOM of svg
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    //get the inner element by id
    var delta = svgDoc.getElementById('myAnimationElement');

$('body').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
    function () {
        var zzz = document.getElementById('myAnimationElement');
        var thing = document.getElementById('arm');
        zzz.beginElement();
        $('#arm').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: @hjpotter92, can you expand on your answer please? thx.

Comment: You cannot get the contentDocument of an <img> due to security restrictions. You also have duplicate id's in the same document. It is possible to trigger svg animations from any event.